# Get list of all rooms in outlook

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, exchange-server, mapi

I'm writing some application where I need to get an all available rooms within my organization. (the same list we get while we opening "Add Rooms" dialog in outlook)
I assume that while we doing it through outlook he works against some exchange server, the question is is there a way to use outlook as a"proxy" between me to the exchange server?

I have no knowledge with exchange, and a little knowledge with outlook's interop...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use the EWS Managed API, thats the right way and way easier than find a way around ;-) [Getting a room by using the EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/hh532566(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Comment: Already saw that, but the thing is that how to create the service ? I saw some examples on the web, but non of them worked for me ...

Comment: from some reason the GetRoomList return an empty collection...