# MAPI access to Exchange Server 2010 vs EWS

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to access some room mailbox information from a web application while connecting to Exchange Server 2010. Using the EWS, I am unable to get some AD properties such as room capacity or customly defined properties for the given rooms. However, querying directly through LDAP is not an option since the web application is external and has no access to any domain controllers.

From what I saw, a viable option would be to use MAPI in order to get the contacts from Exchange and then look for the given properties. In order to perform this kind of integration, I have the following questions:

1) Is it possible to use a standalone version of the MAPI interfaces - i.e. without Outlook installed - ?

2) Can MAPI client functions and objects be used from a server environment - i.e. no user input available - ?

3) Is there any way to use MAPI from managed code - C# or others - ?

4) Are there any other options of getting the aforementioned properties from Exchange?

Answer (score 3):

1, 2 & 3) Yes. I use [Redemption library](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) for this

4) I only know about EWS & Mapi, so I think there is no other way.

Note: Before going ahead you should be sure these information are available from MAPI. Because Exchange is different from Active Directory.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853531/get-list-of-all-rooms-in-outlook) SO question may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I am not in the position of purchasing any third party library.